# Python Image Library produces a crappy quality jpeg when I resize a picture

Tags: python, image, file, encoding, python-imaging-library

I use the Python Image Library (PIL) to resize an image and create a thumbnail.
Why is it that my code produces an image that is so crappy and low-quality? Can someone tell me how to modify the code so that it's the highest quality JPEG?

```
def create_thumbnail(buffer, width=100, height=100):
    im = Image.open(StringIO(buffer))
    if im.mode not in ('L', 'RGB', 'RGBA'):
        im = im.convert('RGB')
    im.thumbnail((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumbnail_file = StringIO()
    im.save(thumbnail_file, 'JPEG')
    thumbnail_file.seek(0)
    return thumbnail_file
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Documentation sayyyyys](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-jpeg.htm):

```
im.save(thumbnail_file, 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this might help someone:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("2.jpg")
image.thumbnail((256, 256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save("11.jpg", quality=100)
```

Comment: Generally speaking, saving a jpg with "100% quality" doesn't noticeably increase the quality over, say, 90%, but just increases the filesize.